# Efficient way to construct nested json?

Tags: spring-boot

Request something like below, it will come as json and set in pojo class:

```
public class Account {
Public Sim sim;
Public Device device;
Public Line line;
}

Reponse(From request bean need to construct below response) :

{
    "messageHeader": {
        "serviceId": "string",
        "requestType": "string",
        "referenceNumber": "string"
    },
    "data": {
        "transactionId": "string",
        "code": "string",
        "reason": "string",
        "message": {
            "eligibilityDetails": {
                "newActivation": "Boolean",
                "eacs": "Boolean",
                "changeDevice": "Boolean",
                "transferWatch": "Boolean",
                "manageWatch": "Boolean",
                "warrantyExchange": "Boolean"
            },
            "lineDetails": {
                "lineId": "120009",
                "displayName": "QELP 01",
                "mdn": [
                    {
                        "type": "mdn",
                        "value": "7203155658"
                    }
                ],
                "deviceId": [
                    {
                        "type": "imageURL",
                        "value": "String"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "make",
                        "value": "APL"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "model",
                        "value": "Iphone XS"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "mode",
                        "value": "4G"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "deviceType",
                        "value": "phone"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "deviceImei",
                        "value": "358671091947537"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "deviceName",
                        "value": "Apple Iphone XS RED"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "isCdmaLess",
                        "value": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "wifiMAC",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ],
                "status": [
                    {
                        "type": "lineStatus",
                        "value": "Active"
                    }
                ],
                "simId": [
                    {
                        "type": "iccid",
                        "value": "35867109194753727"
                    }
                ],
                "retailPlan": {
                    "id": "SWAP001",
                    "name": "Smartwatch Access",
                    "dataIncluded": -1.0,
                    "dataLimit": null,
                    "categoryName": "Unlimited"
                },
                "settings": {
                    "ildEnabled": false,
                    "roamingEnabled": true,
                    "notificationsEnabled": [
                        {}
                    ],
                    "sharedDataYn": false,
                    "dataPolicyApplied": false
                },
                "prospectDeviceId": [
                    {
                        "type": "imageURL",
                        "value": "String"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "make",
                        "value": "APL"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "model",
                        "value": "Iphone XS"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "mode",
                        "value": "4G"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "deviceType",
                        "value": "phone"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "deviceImei",
                        "value": "358671091947537"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "deviceName",
                        "value": "Apple Iphone XS RED"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "isCdmaLess",
                        "value": "false"
                    },
                    {
                        "type": "wifiMAC",
                        "value": ""
                    }
                ],
                "lineWearable": {
                    "lineId": "120009",
                    "displayName": "SWP 01",
                    "mdn": [
                        {
                            "type": "mdn",
                            "value": "7203155659"
                        }
                    ],
                    "deviceId": [
                        {
                            "type": "imageURL",
                            "value": "String"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "make",
                            "value": "APL"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "model",
                            "value": "Watch Series 6"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "mode",
                            "value": "4G"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "deviceType",
                            "value": "smartwatch"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "deviceImei",
                            "value": "358671091947538"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "deviceName",
                            "value": "Apple Watch 6 RED"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "isCdmaLess",
                            "value": "false"
                        },
                        {
                            "type": "wifiMAC",
                            "value": ""
                        }
                    ],
                    "status": [
                        {
                            "type": "lineStatus",
                            "value": "Prospect"
                        }
                    ],
                    "simId": [
                        {
                            "type": "uiccid",
                            "value": "35867109194753729"
                        }
                    ],
                    "retailPlan": {
                        "id": "SWAP001",
                        "name": "Smartwatch Access",
                        "dataIncluded": -1.0,
                        "dataLimit": null,
                        "categoryName": "Unlimited"
                    },
                    "prospectDeviceId": [
                        {}
                    ]
                }
            }
        },
        "additionalData": [
            {
                "name": "string",
                "value": "string"
            }
        ]   
    }
}
```

I will be receiving request by setting values in bean as nested bean request. Then i need to get the value from the bean to construct the nested json response.

Kindly tell me the efficient and minimum code required to achieve this. Becoz nested json response seems like big.

Comment: how does the json response look like?

Comment: u mean request json?